# Solidity: Binance smart chain token: Why I can't find definition of transaction fee setting?

Tags: solidity, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain, bep20, bsc

There is the code of one [bsc (binance smart chain) contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0xBdF9631Cdc26BC582F6630620D4bF4ffC2e37694#code).
It is quite clear. But I can't find one thing here.

They have written on the [website](https://tipsysanta.io/#TOKENOMICS) that 2% of each transaction goes to charity, 3% to liquidity pool and 2% are tipsy rewards.
These fee rules are called "Tokenomics", each token may have a different one.

But when I go through their code, I don't see this fee definition setting anywhere.
There is only some limit of fees.

Do you know where this value is specified?
thank you for your answer.

There is part of the code where I can't find important info about transaction fees:

...
full code is [there](https://bscscan.com/address/0xBdF9631Cdc26BC582F6630620D4bF4ffC2e37694#code)

```
contract Token is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    
    address dead = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    
    uint8 public maxLiqFee = 10;
    uint8 public maxTaxFee = 10;
    uint8 public maxBurnFee = 10;
    uint8 public maxWalletFee = 10;
    uint8 public maxBuybackFee = 10;
    uint8 public minMxTxPercentage = 1;
    uint8 public minMxWalletPercentage = 1;
    
    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
    
    address public router = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;
    //address public router = 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1;
    
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 public _tTotal;
    uint256 private _rTotal;
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;
    
    bool public mintedByMudra = true;
    
    string public _name;
    string public _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    
    uint8 public _taxFee = 0;
    uint8 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
    
    uint8 public _liquidityFee = 0;
    uint8 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

    uint8 public _burnFee = 0;
    uint8 private _previousBurnFee = _burnFee;

    uint8 public _walletFee = 0;
    uint8 private _previousWalletFee = _walletFee;

    uint8 public _buybackFee = 0;
    uint8 private _previousBuybackFee = _buybackFee;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable pcsV2Router;
    address public immutable pcsV2Pair;
    address payable public feeWallet;
    
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;    
    
    uint256 public _maxTxAmount;
    uint256 public _maxWalletAmount;
    uint256 public numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;    
    uint256 private buyBackUpperLimit = 1 * 10**18;
    
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }
    
    constructor (address tokenOwner,string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol, uint8 decimal, uint256 amountOfTokenWei,
        uint8 setMxTxPer, uint8 setMxWalletPer,
        address payable _feeWallet
        )  {
            
        _name = tokenName;
        _symbol = tokenSymbol;
        _decimals = decimal;
        _tTotal = amountOfTokenWei;
        _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
        
        _rOwned[tokenOwner] = _rTotal;

        feeWallet = _feeWallet;
        

        _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(setMxTxPer).div(
            10**2
        );
        _maxWalletAmount = _tTotal.mul(setMxWalletPer).div(
            10**2
        );
        
        numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = amountOfTokenWei.mul(1).div(1000);
        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _pcsV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(router);
            // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        pcsV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_pcsV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _pcsV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        pcsV2Router = _pcsV2Router;
        
        _isExcludedFromFee[tokenOwner] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        
        emit Transfer(address(0), tokenOwner, _tTotal);
    }

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _tTotal;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
        return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function isExcludedFromReward(address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isExcluded[account];
    }

    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tFeeTotal;
    }

    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }

    function reflectionFromToken(uint256 tAmount, bool deductTransferFee) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(tAmount <= _tTotal, "Amt must be less than supply");
        if (!deductTransferFee) {
            (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rAmount;
        } else {
            (,uint256 rTransferAmount,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
            return rTransferAmount;
        }
    }

    function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
        require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amt must be less than tot refl");
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        return rAmount.div(currentRate);
    }

    function excludeFromReward(address account) public onlyOwner() {
        require(!_isExcluded[account], "Account is already excluded from reward");
        if(_rOwned[account] > 0) {
            _tOwned[account] = tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
        }
        _isExcluded[account] = true;
        _excluded.push(account);
    }

    function includeInReward(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(_isExcluded[account], "Already excluded");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_excluded[i] == account) {
                _excluded[i] = _excluded[_excluded.length - 1];
                _tOwned[account] = 0;
                _isExcluded[account] = false;
                _excluded.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    
    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }
    
    function setAllFeePercent(uint8 taxFee, uint8 liquidityFee, uint8 burnFee, uint8 walletFee, uint8 buybackFee) external onlyOwner() {
        require(taxFee >= 0 && taxFee <=maxTaxFee,"TF err");
        require(liquidityFee >= 0 && liquidityFee <=maxLiqFee,"LF err");
        require(burnFee >= 0 && burnFee <=maxBurnFee,"BF err");
        require(walletFee >= 0 && walletFee <=maxWalletFee,"WF err");
        require(buybackFee >= 0 && buybackFee <=maxBuybackFee,"BBF err");
        _taxFee = taxFee;
        _liquidityFee = liquidityFee;
        _burnFee = burnFee;
        _buybackFee = buybackFee;
        _walletFee = walletFee;
    }
    
    function buyBackUpperLimitAmount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return buyBackUpperLimit;
    }

    function setBuybackUpperLimit(uint256 buyBackLimit) external onlyOwner() {
        buyBackUpperLimit = buyBackLimit * 10**18;
    }
    
    function setMaxTxPercent(uint256 maxTxPercent) external onlyOwner() {
        require(maxTxPercent >= minMxTxPercentage && maxTxPercent <=100,"err");
        _maxTxAmount = _tTotal.mul(maxTxPercent).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function setMaxWalletPercent(uint256 maxWalletPercent) external onlyOwner() {
        require(maxWalletPercent >= minMxWalletPercentage && maxWalletPercent <=100,"err");
        _maxWalletAmount = _tTotal.mul(maxWalletPercent).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }

    function setFeeWallet(address payable newFeeWallet) external onlyOwner {
        require(newFeeWallet != address(0), "ZERO ADDRESS");
        feeWallet = newFeeWallet;
    }

    
        //to recieve ETH from pcsV2Router when swaping
    receive() external payable {}

    function _reflectFee(uint256 rFee, uint256 tFee) private {
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rFee);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tFee);
    }

    function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getTValues(tAmount);
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, _getRate());
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getTValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 tFee = calculateTaxFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tLiquidity = calculateLiquidityFee(tAmount);
        uint256 tTransferAmount = tAmount.sub(tFee).sub(tLiquidity);
        return (tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity);
    }

    function _getRValues(uint256 tAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 currentRate) private pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rAmount = tAmount.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rFee = tFee.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        uint256 rTransferAmount = rAmount.sub(rFee).sub(rLiquidity);
        return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee);
    }

    function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
        (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
        return rSupply.div(tSupply);
    }

    function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
        uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
            if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
            tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        }
        if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    }
    
    function _takeLiquidity(uint256 tLiquidity) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
        uint256 rLiquidity = tLiquidity.mul(currentRate);
        _rOwned[address(this)] = _rOwned[address(this)].add(rLiquidity);
        if(_isExcluded[address(this)])
            _tOwned[address(this)] = _tOwned[address(this)].add(tLiquidity);
    }
    
    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_taxFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }

    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount.mul(_liquidityFee + _burnFee + _walletFee + _buybackFee).div(
            10**2
        );
    }
    
    function removeAllFee() private {
        if(_taxFee == 0 && _liquidityFee == 0 && _burnFee == 0 && _walletFee == 0 && _buybackFee == 0) return;
        
        _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;
        _previousBurnFee = _burnFee;
        _previousWalletFee = _walletFee;
        _previousBuybackFee = _buybackFee;
        
        _taxFee = 0;
        _liquidityFee = 0;
        _burnFee = 0;
        _walletFee = 0;
        _buybackFee = 0;
    }
    
    function restoreAllFee() private {
        _taxFee = _previousTaxFee;
        _liquidityFee = _previousLiquidityFee;
        _burnFee = _previousBurnFee;
        _walletFee = _previousWalletFee;
        _buybackFee = _previousBuybackFee;
    }
    
    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        if(from != owner() && to != owner())
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");

        if(from != owner() && to != owner() && to != address(0) && to != dead && to != pcsV2Pair){
            uint256 contractBalanceRecepient = balanceOf(to);
            require(contractBalanceRecepient + amount <= _maxWalletAmount, "Exceeds maximum wallet amount"); 
        }
        // is the token balance of this contract address over the min number of
        // tokens that we need to initiate a swap + liquidity lock?
        // also, don't get caught in a circular liquidity event.
        // also, don't swap & liquify if sender is uniswap pair.
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
        {
            contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
        }
        
        bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
        if (
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            to == pcsV2Pair &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled
        ) {
            if(overMinTokenBalance){
                contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
                //add liquidity
                swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
            }
            if(_buybackFee !=0){
                uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
                if (balance > uint256(1 * 10**18)) {
                    
                    if (balance > buyBackUpperLimit)
                        balance = buyBackUpperLimit;
                    
                    buyBackTokens(balance.div(100));
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        //indicates if fee should be deducted from transfer
        bool takeFee = true;
        
        //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
        
        //transfer amount, it will take tax, burn, liquidity fee
        _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
    }

    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        //This needs to be distributed among burn, wallet and liquidity
        //burn
        uint8 totFee  = _burnFee + _walletFee + _liquidityFee + _buybackFee; 
        uint256 spentAmount = 0;
        uint256 totSpentAmount = 0;
        if(_burnFee != 0){
            spentAmount  = contractTokenBalance.div(totFee).mul(_burnFee);
            _tokenTransferNoFee(address(this), dead, spentAmount);
            totSpentAmount = spentAmount;
        }

        if(_walletFee != 0){
            spentAmount = contractTokenBalance.div(totFee).mul(_walletFee);
            _tokenTransferNoFee(address(this), feeWallet, spentAmount);
            totSpentAmount = totSpentAmount + spentAmount;
        }

        if(_buybackFee != 0){
            spentAmount = contractTokenBalance.div(totFee).mul(_buybackFee);
            swapTokensForBNB(spentAmount);
            totSpentAmount = totSpentAmount + spentAmount;
        }

        if(_liquidityFee != 0){
            contractTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance.sub(totSpentAmount);

            // split the contract balance into halves
            uint256 half = contractTokenBalance.div(2);
            uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance.sub(half);

            // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
            // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
            // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
            // has been manually sent to the contract
            uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

            // swap tokens for ETH
            swapTokensForBNB(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

            // how much ETH did we just swap into?
            uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

            // add liquidity to uniswap
            addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);

            emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
        }

    }

    function buyBackTokens(uint256 amount) private lockTheSwap {
        if (amount > 0) {
            swapBNBForTokens(amount);
        }
    }

    function swapTokensForBNB(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pcsV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(pcsV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        pcsV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function swapBNBForTokens(uint256 amount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = pcsV2Router.WETH();
        path[1] = address(this);

      // make the swap
        pcsV2Router.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: amount}(
            0, // accept any amount of Tokens
            path,
            dead, // Burn address
            block.timestamp.add(300)
        );        
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(pcsV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // add the liquidity
        pcsV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            dead,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    //this method is responsible for taking all fee, if takeFee is true
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {
        if(!takeFee)
            removeAllFee();
        
        if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
        } else {
            _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
        
        if(!takeFee)
            restoreAllFee();
    }

    function _transferStandard(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferToExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);           
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _transferBothExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount) private {
        (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tTransferAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);        
        _takeLiquidity(tLiquidity);
        _reflectFee(rFee, tFee);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
    }

    function _tokenTransferNoFee(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();  
        uint256 rAmount = amount.mul(currentRate);   

        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rAmount); 
        
        if (_isExcluded[sender]) {
            _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(amount);
        } 
        if (_isExcluded[recipient]) {
            _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(amount);
        } 
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function recoverBEP20(address tokenAddress, uint256 tokenAmount) public onlyOwner {
        // do not allow recovering self token
        require(tokenAddress != address(this), "Self withdraw");
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(owner(), tokenAmount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the taxes are defined here. However they are initialized to 0, they are probably modified once the contract is deployed.

```
uint8 public _taxFee = 0;
uint8 private _previousTaxFee = _taxFee;

uint8 public _liquidityFee = 0;
uint8 private _previousLiquidityFee = _liquidityFee;

uint8 public _burnFee = 0;
uint8 private _previousBurnFee = _burnFee;

uint8 public _walletFee = 0;
uint8 private _previousWalletFee = _walletFee;

uint8 public _buybackFee = 0;
uint8 private _previousBuybackFee = _buybackFee;
```